# loadData just won't work

Tags: jsgrid

Below is my complete code. There are no errors and `Directory is empty` is shown.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#table").jsGrid({
            width: "100%",
            height: "auto",
            paging: false,
            autoload: false,
            noDataContent: "Directory is empty",

            controller: {
                loadData: function(filter) {
                    var data = {
                        data: [{
                            nickname: "test",
                            email: "t@gmail.com"
                        }]
                    };
                    console.log(data);
                    return data;
                }
            },
            fields: [{
                name: "nickname",
                type: "text",
                width: 80,
                title: "Name"
            }, {
                name: "email",
                type: "text",
                width: 100,
                title: "Email Address",
                readOnly: false
            }]
        });
    });
</script>
```

The console output is as below. Is there anything incorrect about the formatting?

[image]

Is there a way to enable more diagnostics, like printing out what data it is actually receiving so as to allow troubleshooting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set [`autoload:true`](http://js-grid.com/docs/#autoload-default-false)

## `autoload (default false)`

A boolean value specifying whether `controller.loadData` will be called when grid is rendered.

And also you need to return `data.data` inside of [`loadData()`](http://js-grid.com/docs/#loaddatafilter-promisedataresult) mehtod because you have array inside of data.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
controller: {
    loadData: function(filter) {

        var data = {
            data: [{
                nickname: "test",
                email: "t@gmail.com"
            }]
        };
        return data.data; //As per your data array is like this console.log(data.data) so you need to send like this data.data
    }
},
```

**DEMO**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#table").jsGrid({
        width: "100%",
        height: "auto",
        paging: false,

        //for loadData method Need to set auto load true
        autoload: true,

        noDataContent: "Directory is empty",

        controller: {
            loadData: function(filter) {
            
            alert('Table load data method fire because we have set config autoload:true')
                var data = {
                    data: [{
                        nickname: "test",
                        email: "t@gmail.com"
                    }]
                };
                return data.data;//As per your data array is like this console.log(data.data) so you need to send like this data.data
            }
        },

        fields: [{
            name: "nickname",
            type: "text",
            width: 80,
            title: "Name"
        }, {
            name: "email",
            type: "text",
            width: 100,
            title: "Email Address",
            readOnly: false
        }]
    });
    
    $("#table1").jsGrid({
        width: "100%",
        height: "auto",
        paging: false,

        //for loadData method will not work with auto load false
        autoload: false,

        noDataContent: "Directory is empty",

        controller: {
            loadData: function(filter) {
               alert('Table 1 load data method not fire')
                return []
            }
        },

        fields: [{
            name: "nickname",
            type: "text",
            width: 80,
            title: "Name"
        }, {
            name: "email",
            type: "text",
            width: 100,
            title: "Email Address",
            readOnly: false
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid-theme.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid.min.js"></script>


<div id="table"></div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="table1"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! My `autoload` was true, but I set it false while testing different permutations. It was the `data.data` that does the trick.

Comment: yes because jsgrid will accept data inform of Array. So need to pass an array of data.